# Alternatives to Struts2-jquery plugin for uploading files in Struts2 using Ajax

Tags: ajax, struts2

I want to upload a file using the < s:file > tag, but Struts2 doesn't support Ajax for this functionality, as far as I know. I tried to do it using the Struts2 jquery plugin but it overwrites some jquery functions that i need an can't change right now (like .dialog()).

Is there an alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many jquery based plugins for this purpose.
I am using [this library](http://pixelcone.com/jquery/ajax-file-upload-script/). Its the most simple and elegant plugin, minimal requirements and lots of options.

Here are some other plugins which I considered(my preference was a plugin which doesnt use flash)

- [This one](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) shows thumbnail before uploading and also overall progress
- [This one](http://exposureroom.biz/upload.aspx) shows remaining time, uploading speed and remaining size

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it (I'm not using JQuery):

1. I hide an iframe inside my page. I give it an id (iframe for example) and a name (the same than the id).
2. I set the attribute "target" on my form to the id of the hidden iframe (then, the response from the server is loaded inside the iframe.
3. I register an event handler on the iframe to react on the onload event. The handler analyse the response from the server. Alternatively, I sometime just return javascript code from the server in a `<script>` tag. This code performs action on the client upon success or failure of the intended action.

If you like the idea, you may want to read this [article](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/) or [this one](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/):